# Rails unpermitted parameter but model creation still working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I keep getting an `unpermitted parameter` error, but the model creation is still working. Adding or removing `:active_comment_relationship` in the strong parameters makes no difference. What's wrong with the code?

notices_controller.rb:

```
@notice = @character.notices.build(notice_params)
if @notice.save
  .
  .

def notice_params
  params.require(:notice).permit( :content, :picture, :latitude, :longitude, # :active_comment_relationship, # adding or removing :active_comment_relationship makes no difference
                                  active_comment_relationship_attributes: [:commentee_id] )
end
```

notice.rb:

```
has_one  :active_comment_relationship, class_name: "Commentrelationship",
                                       foreign_key: "commenter_id",
                                       dependent: :destroy
has_one  :supernotice, through: :active_comment_relationship, source: :commentee
accepts_nested_attributes_for :active_comment_relationship
```

_notice_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(:notice, url: :notices, method: :post, multiple: true, remote: true ) do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :callsign, @character.callsign %>
  <%= f.fields_for :active_comment_relationship do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.hidden_field :commentee_id, value: nil %>
  <% end %>
  .
  .
<% end %>
```

logs:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"UoJ...ieQ==",
"callsign"=>"bazzer",
"notice"=>{
  "active_comment_relationship"=>{"commentee_id"=>""}, 
  "latitude"=>"54.00292618287952", 
  "longitude"=>"-1.1480712890625", 
  "content"=>"Hello."},
"Drop"=>""}
Character Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "characters".* FROM "characters" WHERE "characters"."callsign" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["callsign", "bazzer"]]
User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
CACHE (0.1ms)  SELECT  "characters".* FROM "characters" WHERE "characters"."callsign" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["callsign", "bazzer"]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Unpermitted parameter: active_comment_relationship
```

Comment: What does your form view look like?  You're supposed to be submitting a param with the name notice[active_comment_relationship_attributes].

Comment: Is there a problem? Your model gets created and the unpermitted parameter ignored. If you'd like rails to raise an exception for unpermitted params in development, add this to your `development.rb` file: `config.action_controller.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = :raise`.